# How to get the infobox data of Wikipedia?

Tags: javascript, wikipedia-api

I am making a website that will automatically get the data from wikipedia using `Wikipedia API`. What I have already tries is to use `find('.infobox')` to find the infobox data.

However, I only want to get the data below the horizontal line in the infobox(starting from disease: covid in the photo below)

Here is the code I currently had:

```
let area = "Canada"
var url="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=COVID-19_pandemic_in_"+area +"&redirects&prop=text&callback=?";
$.getJSON(url,function(data){
     wikiHTML = data.parse.text["*"];
$wikiDOM = $("<document>"+wikiHTML+"</document>");
var info= $wikiDOM.find('.infobox').html();
console.log(info)
```

This will display all the information in the infobox.

Could anyone give me an idea or a solution that tell me how to do that?

Also, the image from wikipedia will not be able to display which will show error of `invalid url` (the image area will display `alt` text) Is there a way to choose not to display image before displaying which will prevent the image (`alt text`) and `error` in `console` ?

Thanks for any responds!

*In the image below, I only want to get the data from `disease: Covid-19` to `Vaccinations`

[image]

Comment: @Tgr, I have checked this answer before I asked the question. But fortunately, the answer below has solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to filter  element depending on the conditions.

> I only want to get the data from disease: Covid-19 to Vaccinations

You can look at the  element that encloses these information and find things in common. I see each  element includes `th.infobox-label`.

Check if other element does not have the same structure.

If not, filtering the  element by whether the element includes `th.infobox-label` will work out.